# Populate a dropdown with previous user input

Tags: javascript

I have a text input where user have to enter their surname and I want that surname as they enter it to appear below in a dropdown, using HTML and Javascript. This is my code so far but it does not work:

```
<form id= 'surnameReg'>
  <label for='surname'>Surname:</label>
  <input type='text' id="surname">
</form>
<form id='chooseSur'>
  <label for="who">Who:</label>
  <select id="who">
  </select>
</form>
```

And my JS:

```
function drop() {
  var surnArr=[];
  var select = document.getElementById("who");
  for(var i = 0; i <surnArr.length; i++) {
    var sur= surnArr[i];
    var op = document.createElement("option");
    op.textContent = sur;
    op.value = sur;
    select.appendChild(op);
  }
}
```

Comment: How is `surnArr` getting populated? Where is `drop()` being used? I don't see enough details here in your example to show a reproducible issue.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want an autofill drop down based on the characters the user enters as each one is entered? Also, is surnArr populated somewhere you aren't showing us? Otherwise you're iterating through an empty array of size 0, 0 times.

Comment: @idream1nc0de I'm starting to think this is a "I don't know where to start" question more than a question designed for this site - but hoping clarification will prove me wrong?

Comment: Poni, I think you want something like https://github.com/TarekRaafat/autoComplete.js

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event listener on the first form on `submit` and then create and append the `option` as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("surnameReg").addEventListener("submit",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     let surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
     if(surname){
          var select = document.getElementById("who");
          var op = document.createElement("option");
          op.textContent = surname;
          op.value = surname;
          select.appendChild(op);
     }
});
```

```html
<form id= 'surnameReg'   >
     <label for='surname'>Surname:</label>
     <input type='text'  id="surname" >
</form>
<form id='chooseSur' >
     <label for="who">Who:</label>
     <select id="who">
     </select>
</form>
```